# Searching Windows by File Type

Tags: windows, search

Although Windows defines the file type on the basis of the file extension, some types cover multiple extensions (e.g., "JPEG Image" covers `.JPG` and `.JPEG`), and others use extensions that are substrings of other extensions for unrelated types (e.g., "Markdown files" are `.md`, which is a substring of `.mdb` (an Access database) and `.mdi` (Microsoft Document Image file). If I want to search for "JPEG Image", or "Markdown file", and get *only* the required file types... how do I do it?

1. Explorer, batch, or PowerShell solutions are acceptable.
2. The ideal solution will work for both Windows 7 and Windows 10, but separate solutions for Windows 7 and Windows 10 are also acceptable.
3. I would prefer not having to analyze and use explicit file extensions in the search.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking.  Are you trying to **sort** or **search** for files with a specific type?  If you are trying to search for a specific type (Like `.JPEG`), why do you not wish to search by the extension?

Comment: Search, not sort; and searching by the extension in some cases will not get all of the files of the type (e.g., `.JPEG` misses the "JPEG Images" that are `.JPG`), and in other cases will get too many files (e.g., `.md` in the Explorer search box will get not only "Markdown files", but "Access database files" (`.mdb`)).

Comment: For the case of `.JPG` and `.JPEG`, since they are both technically `.JPEG` files.  You can search using explorer by typing `type:=.JPEG` in the search box and it should find all .JPEG files, regardless of their extension

Comment: Nope. `type:=.JPEG` omits `.JPG`.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped.  Give `type:.jpeg` a try.  I just tested it now and it returned both `.jpg` and `.jpeg` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things about Windows and the search function in the File Explorer:

1. Windows doesn't know about mime-types such as "JPEG Image" or "Markdown file" (or their respective (sub-/super-)types
2. The search is very powerful, if used correctly.

To answer your question:

To search for a specific extension (file type in Windows) use the search query:

- Search for all `.md` files and only those files (should be markdown files): `type:".md"` (remember the quotation marks, if you want an exact match)
- Search for all images: `kind:=image` (yes, you can search for this)
- You can combine all filters and search terms how you like it.

More info and examples here: https://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7/

Comment: +1.  Although you *can* search for some files regardless of the sub types.  Not sure about all types, but some allow you to.  Such as `.JPEG`, which will find all of the sub types such as `.JPE .JPG .JFIF` if you search with `type:.jpeg`  Also, it does not seem quotations are required, but return the same result.

Comment: @CheesusCrust the quotation marks are required when searching for an exact match. Otherwise `.mdb` files (like the OP stated) are found.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I thought the OP meant to find more rather than less.  Whoops!   Thanks for sharing the link too.

Comment: The link doesn't really make it clear how to do what I needed - I'd actually found that link in my research - but between the answer and comments here, plus a bit of digging for information on Windows Search Advanced Query Syntax, I've been able to put together what I need. (Next step: see if I can figure out how to do it in PowerShell...)

Comment: `type:".md"` did not work (false negatives - no matches) when I tried it on Windows 10 (in a folder with 11 .md files).

Comment: @GiantTree, as Peter Mortensen explains, `type:".md"` is not correct. It should be `type:=".md"` with an =. I'd suggest testing it, and then please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To search in Windows using the "type:" syntax, you want to do

`type:~`  Note the tilde.

For example I wanted to find Word Documents, where if you're looking in explorer browser, the "Type" column will identify as "Microsoft Word Document", I used:

`type:~"Microsoft Word Document"`

The results returnd only Word Docs and even highlighted the text in the "Type" column.

I had tried repeatedly with `type:` and `type:=` to no avail, only the tilde `~` worked.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Does this work for partial matches, and is it case-sensitive? For example, do I have to use "Microsoft Word Document", or is "word doc" going to be adequate (assuming that I don't have another application that calls itself "«something» Word")

Comment: In any search I've done anywhere the tilde has always meant partial match search or similar, so I'm going to say yes.

Comment: In spite of the time lapse, I've rechecked this, and I need explicit wildcards to match on the "type name" - that is, if I want to match Word documents (and I don't have something other than MSWord that calls itself "Word"), I need to use `type:~"*Word*"`